# How to do capital pi ($\prod$) notation on a TI-84 calculator?

Tags: calculus, calculator

I am trying to figure out how to input product notation into my TI-84 Plus graphing calculator. I haven't found anything so far.

Is there any function I could use to do this? Maybe even a program I could install on my calculator?

Comment: I suppose it has $\sum$, you can then simply take $\exp(\sum\log\dots)$.

Comment: Why are you using a Ti-84? You could use Wolframalpha, SAGE, or many other types of free software that can do what the Ti-84 can, and so much more.

Answer (score 2):

The [`prod(`](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/prod) command will take the product of elements of a list for you, which handles finite products $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n$ just fine, especially in conjunction with the [`seq(`](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/seq-list) command. For example, if you want to compute $n!$ the roundabout way, you can take

```
prod(seq(I,I,1,N))
```

which is the calculator approach to writing $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n i$.

There's no way to handle infinite products except to the extent that you can approximate them with finite products.

(I'm not sure if the color version of the TI-84 can handle infinite sums with the `Σ(` command; I doubt it. But if it does then you can use that and logarithms to do infinite products.)